# how acces admin theme without /admin in url?

Tags: routes, 8

I try to have an admin theme for admin user and custom theme for user logged in without /admin/.... in the url.

I create an entity content module, the routing is like that :

```
    # AnnonceEntity routing definition
entity.annonce_entity.canonical:
  path: '/admin/annonce_entity/{annonce_entity}'
  defaults:
    _entity_view: 'annonce_entity'
    _title: 'Gestion des annonces'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'annonce_entity.view'

entity.annonce_entity.collection:
  path: '/annonce/liste'
  defaults:
    _entity_list: 'annonce_entity'
    _title: 'Liste des annonces'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'

entity.annonce_entity.add_form:
  path: '/annonce/ajout'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: annonce_entity.add
    _title: 'Ajouter une annonce'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'


entity.annonce_entity.edit_form:
  path: '/annonce/{annonce_entity}/edit'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: annonce_entity.edit
    _title: 'Edit Gestion des annonces'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'

entity.annonce_entity.delete_form:
  path: '/annonce/{annonce_entity}/delete'
  defaults:
    _entity_form: annonce_entity.delete
    _title: 'Delete Gestion des annonces'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'

annonce_entity.settings:
  path: 'admin/structure/annonce_entity'
  defaults:
   _form: '\Drupal\annonce\Entity\Form\AnnonceEntitySettingsForm'
   _title: 'Configuration des annonces'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer gestion des annonces entities'
```

I remove all /admin/ path for get better url for the simple user.

If i do that, it's ok for user admin and simple user but url is not good

```
entity.annonce_entity.collection:
  path: '/admin/annonce/liste'
  defaults:
    _entity_list: 'annonce_entity'
    _title: 'Liste des annonces'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'
```

All is good but the path is /admin/annonce/liste, i prefer /annonce/liste.

Anyone have a suggestion ?

i have take a look into the user module, for the edit profil but i can't find the way to do same, admin theme for user admin and site theme for simple user.

edit:
i have a way with AdminsNegociator service i check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `_admin_route` option.

For example:

```
entity.annonce_entity.collection:
  path: '/annonce/liste'
  defaults:
    _entity_list: 'annonce_entity'
    _title: 'Liste des annonces'
  requirements:
    _user_is_logged_in: 'TRUE'
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
```